# How to efficiently animate 2D scene spanning sprites in Unity?

Tags: unity

Our game is a 2D point-and-click adventure game.  One of the levels is set in a factory with conveyor belts that span the scene.  The game is hand animated in 2D and so animating these conveyor belts could potentially take up lots of memory since the sprites are as long as the screen (it's an HD game - 1920 x 1080).

I'm not sure if tiled sprite shapes can be animated, so I was wondering if there's a prescribed way to handle larger sprite animation like this - efficiently.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of what your conveyors look like? That will help target solutions that can work well with your art style.

Comment: I actually animated conveyor belt in one of my 2.5d games! It was not HD however.. I used array of images for animated factory/belt and separate sprite for product moving on it.. The belt itself could suffice with just few sprites - giving illusion of movement. You could 'cut out' only those pars of image that have movement and animate only them (by swapping sprites) - so will not be any need for swapping the whole HD picture. And separate sprite for product.